# How to get child array data in Parent array in php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Below is my array but i want child data in parent as well as

```
[16363] => Array
        (
            [15] => Array
                (
                    [account_id] => 19321
                    [aum] => 104853.92
                    [cl_user_id] => 16363
                    [text] => MICHAEL ANDRISANO INDIVIDUAL
                    [fname] => MICHAEL
                    [lname] => ANDRISANO
                    [account_number] => 906566540
                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [account_id] => 19322
                    [aum] => 196539.78
                    [cl_user_id] => 16363
                    [text] => MICHAEL ANDRISANO INDIVIDUAL
                    [fname] => MICHAEL
                    [lname] => ANDRISANO
                    [account_number] => 906566600
                )

        )
```

**I want Output like Below**

```
 [16363] => Array
        (
            [text] => MICHAEL ANDRISANO
            [cl_id] => 16363
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                     [account_id] => 19321
                    [aum] => 104853.92
                    [cl_user_id] => 16363
                    [text] => MICHAEL ANDRISANO INDIVIDUAL
                    [fname] => MICHAEL
                    [lname] => ANDRISANO
                    [account_number] => 906566540
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cl_id] => 16363
                            [account_id] => 19322
                            [aum] => 196539.78
                            [text] => MICHAEL ANDRISANO INDIVIDUAL (906566600)
                            [account_number] => 906566600

                        )
                )

        )
```

Comment: Is `[16363]` the root, or is there more to that array? Which i assume there is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli it isn't?! ***Nooooooooooooooooooo*** I will have to research and build my own code from scratch! That's so ISIS! all these hours I spent on here hoping someone can help me make something unique! `:-/`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any of your variable names, but let's say your original array was called `$parent`, and you want it parsed into `$clients`.

Simply loop through each record in `$parent`, and then loop through the child arrays, and put it all together in a new array. Below is an example of how you might do this. The expected output in your question has a different number of keys for the different `[node]` elements, so I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but hopefully this will get you started.

```
<?php
//This is what will be our final array (your expected output)
$clients = array();

foreach ($parent as $key=>$children)
{
    // Build the initial $clients meta data.
    $clients[$key] = array (
        // It seems the following data is identical, so we'll just grab from the first child
        'text' => $children[key($children)]['fname'] . ' ' . $children[key($children)]['lname'],
        'cl_id' => $children[key($children)]['cl_user_id'],
        'nodes' => array()
    );

    // Now populate the nodes
    foreach ($children AS $child)
    {
        $clients[$key]['nodes'][] = array (
            'account_id' => $child['account_id'],
            'cl_id' => $child['cl_id'],
            'aum' => $child['aum'],
            'text' => $child['text'],
            'account_number' => $child['account_number']
        );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this is the perfect solution but one issue with this is in second array i can not get fname and lname

Comment: Hello @Robbie this is perfect answer thank you for this  'text' => $children[0]['fname'] . ' ' . $children[0]['lname']   i am not getting fname and lname i just get in two records only what about other

Comment: @vaibhavPatel, I'm glad my example helps. But I don't quite understand your fname and lname problem. Are you saying that `$output[16363]['cl_id']` ends up being blank, because `$children[0]['fname']` and `$children[0]['lname']` is blank? You mention that you get it in "two records only", but I only see two records in your example in the original post.

Comment: Below is my output 
    [16348] => Array
        (         [text] => KEVIN MCGOVERN
            [cl_id] => 16348
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [account_id] => 19304
                            [cl_id] => 16348
                            [aum] => 0.00
                            [text] => KEVIN MCGOVERN TRUST
                            [account_number] => 922037608
                        )) )

Comment: Below is the second array in this i have no fname lnam becasue some have 2 or more child may be thats why [16349] => Array
        (
            [text] =>  
            [cl_id] => 
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [account_id] => 19305
                            [cl_id] => 16349
                            [aum] => 0.00
                            [text] => KEVIN MCGOVERN TRUST
                            [account_number] => 922037610
                     )))

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. In looking at your original example, it looks like the child arrays don't always have a 0 index (the children you showed had "15" and "16"). I just want any of the child elements, so I'll try use the `key()` function to grab an index that definitely exists. I've edited my answer to update the `text` and `cl_id` population. Can you try that again?

Comment: Great! I noticed that I forgot to use key() for getting the `lname`, so I've just edited the answer again to fix that. Good luck with your project.